# Pathos multiprocessing in class produces garbled standard output

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm trying to use multiprocessing in a class I have written to speed up calculations. I'm using pathos.multiprocessing and dill, and using map on a ProcessingPool. I've tested the functionality of multiprocessing in a console and it performed as expected. The issue I'm having is that when I try to implement it in my code, as soon as it calls pool.map the terminal I'm using starts spitting out ridiculous nonsense. The output is recognizable as being from the code, but I have no idea how it's making it print. Some of it comes from a method like I defined below, where it includes the current datetime. In the nonsense I see that it's printing the current time, after pool.map was called, so this isn't just something that's just being repeatedly printed out, it's new output. Here is a little code illustrating how I'm using multiprocessing.

My_func is a little more complicated than I have below, but as a first step I changed it to literally what is written below, and the problem still persists.

Additionally, Ctr-C does trigger a KeyboardInterrupt, but does not completely stop the program. I'm using Visual Studio and python 2.7.13 on Windows 10.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
import dill
import datetime

class my_class(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=4)

        p1 = [1,2,3]
        p2 = [4,5,6]
        p3 = [7,8,9]

        results = pool.map(self.my_func, p1, p2, p3)

    def my_func(self,x,y,z):
        print(x,y,z)

    def status_printout(self,message):
        header = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(header+' -- '+message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives) to ensure only one of the subprocesses writes to stdout at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the suggested

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
```

for Windows. Things are behaving normally now.